# Building VC++ 2008 project with VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using VC++ 2008 express edition and Visual studio 2012 and 2013 professional version. I need to build a vc++ 2008 project with VS 2013 as formatting and intellisense are not good with vc++ 2008 express edition. But I'm getting the following issue. And in Platform Toolset in project property it is displaying as "Visual Studio 2008 (v90) (not installed)"

How to resolve this issue

> error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2008 (Platform Toolset = 'v90') cannot be found. To build using the v90 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2008 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...".    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets   64  5   glmRainbowRichesEInstant

Answer (score 2):

the following worked for me:
Download [SDK 7.1 DVD](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442), mount it on your device and install the missing complilers from `\Setup\vc_stdx86` and/or `\Setup\vc_stdamd64`.

The problem is also discussed on [Need to run v90 Platform Tools on VS2013 in a Windows 10 TP box (10074)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6978fdc-df1e-466c-953f-9e20a75a09ce/need-to-run-v90-platform-tools-on-vs2013-in-a-windows-10-tp-box-10074?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Comment: Installing just the vc_stdx86 was enough for me to get VS2022 to recognize both x86 and x64 for a VS2008 project.
I'm not sure, but I suspect it just causes a better .props file to be installed somewhere, the VS2010 compilers themselves in this SDK aren't actually used.