# Conversion from a VS2013 project to VS2015 one

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I had run into a problem when I tried to have a VS2013 project be complied with VS2015. The project is originally compiled with VS2008 and still need some libraries to be complied with newer VS version.

I installed in the order of VS2008 -> VS2015, and the I got a error message

```
"The build tools for Visual Studio 2008 (Platform Toolset = 'v90') cannot be found."
```

According the message and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173296/building-vc-2008-project-with-vs-2013), I additionally installed vc_stdx86.msi and vc_stdamd64.msi from the .iso file. Then, the error message changed into

```
"Required file "" is missing."
```

where

```
<CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' == 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true'"
```

I have made some search about "ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader" but couldn't get a solution. Could anyone suggests what is the missing file and how can I get rid of the error?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't ship with a platform toolset *that* old, that's why it fails to compile.

Changing it to the platform toolset of VS2015 (v140) will fix that issue, but you may get some other errors possibly, as there may have been breaking changes in 7 years (I think).

Go to `Project -> [Name] Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General` and change `Platform Toolset` to `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`.